# ¿Como puedo mostrar el contenido ingresado en un JTextfield en un JOptionPane (En un formulario)?

Tags: java, formularios, jtextfield

Este el código de mi formulario, la parte del JOptionPane es donde tengo el problema.
//LDVives = Lugar donde vives

```
private void txtNombreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtNombre.getText();
    txtEdad.getText();
    txtLDVives.getText();
}                                         

private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tus datos son\nNombre: "+txtNombre+"\nEdad: "+txtEdad+"\nLugar donde Vives: "+txtLDVives);
}
```

Comment: `txtNombre.getText();` regresa algo, y tu no haces nada con ello así es que es como si no lo pusieras, remplaza txtNombre en la parte de abajo  por txtNombre.getText() y tal vez haga lo que quieres

Comment: Gracias, si funciono.

Comment: Excelente, agrego la respuesta esperando que algún día le pueda servir a alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se halla en esta sección:

```
private void btnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tus datos son\nNombre: "+txtNombre+"\nEdad: "+txtEdad+"\nLugar donde Vives: "+txtLDVives);
}
```

Lo que estás tratando de imprimir son las variables, por ejemplo `txtNombre` que me imagino que es de tipo `JTextField` y te debe imprimir su representación en cadena, en vez de la representacion en cadena de su contenido.

Los componentes gráficos ya implementan la especificación [Java Bean](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) y por ello mismo cuentan con métodos llamados ***accesors***, que en concreto para tu caso son Setter y Getter.

setNombre establece el valor, mientras que getNombre lee el valor de una variable llamada nombre, a´si funciona esa convención tan ampliamente usada.

Por dicho motivo remplaza las llamadas a los campos por una llamada a su propiedad texto, es decir: `txtNombre.getText()` para obtener el texto dentro del `JTextField` llamado `txtNombre` y que se debería de llamar internamente `text`.

Tu código quedaría como:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tus datos son\nNombre: "+txtNombre.getText()+"\nEdad: "+txtEdad.getText()+"\nLugar donde Vives: "+txtLDVives.getText());
```